# Springboot websecurity blockage

Tags: java, angular, jwt, websecurity

Hi im trying to learn web security using jwt authentification in springboot but i have a problem even though i have a good configuration :

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

You can see there that the path api/auth/** is all permited to acces but when i use a post request to try to sign up or sign in it says that i dont have authorizations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZiCB.png) this is the postman response to my request.

Thanks for helping me i'm on this for days